# MySQL Join table then Order By slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using this version of MySQL `Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.4-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2` and here is my server cpu info:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

[image]

I have 2 tables. Office and Customer. I have 1 row in my Office table and 1 Millions in Customer. You can see tables structure here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afa8f7

`show create table customers;`

```
customers | CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_office` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '    ',
  `familyname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `archive` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `id_company` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `revision` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_office_2` (`id_office`,`code`),
  KEY `id_office` (`id_office`),
  KEY `id_company` (`id_company`),
  KEY `archive` (`archive`),
  KEY `firstname` (`firstname`),
  KEY `idx` (`id_office`,`firstname`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customers_company` FOREIGN KEY (`id_company`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customers_offices` FOREIGN KEY (`id_office`) REFERENCES `offices` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1019063 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

`show create table offices;`

```
offices | CREATE TABLE `offices` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_company` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `archive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `prefix` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `contract_auto_number` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `customer_auto_number` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `email_synchro` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `email_customer_synchro` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `revision` smallint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_company` (`id_company`),
  KEY `code_UNIQUE` (`code`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `description` (`description`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_offices_company` FOREIGN KEY (`id_company`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

1st explain:

```
explain SELECT c.id, c.firstname FROM customers c ORDER BY c.firstname;
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | c     | index | NULL          | firstname | 138     | NULL | 1017401 | Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

2nd explain:

```
explain SELECT c.id, c.firstname FROM customers c INNER JOIN offices o ON(c.id_office = o.id) ORDER BY c.firstname;
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------------+------------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys             | key        | key_len | ref       | rows   | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------------+------------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | o     | index | PRIMARY                   | id_company | 4       | NULL      | 1      | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref   | id_office_2,id_office,idx | idx        | 4       | mced.o.id | 508700 | Using index                                  |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------------+------------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I do this query and it's very fast (0.00003 seconds):

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstname
FROM customers c
ORDER BY c.firstname
LIMIT 25;
```

Now I do this query and it's very slow (3 seconds)

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstname
FROM customers c INNER JOIN offices o ON(c.id_office = o.id)  
ORDER BY c.firstname
LIMIT 25;
```

There is a way to speed up the query ? Or the problem is my server CPU number ?

Comment: Please provide your table schema's and importantly if you  have any index's setup

Comment: @Zachary I did you can click on the sqlfiddle link

Comment: I find it hard to believe the first query takes only .00003 seconds and returns a million rows.  what aren't you telling us?

Comment: I know you provide the sql to create your whole schema in the fiddle, but it would be much more helpful if you could edit your question to show (as text, not image or a link) output of `show create table customers;` and `show create table offices;` and `explain SELECT rest-of-your-query` for the two queries

Comment: @ysth In fact, I did my queries in phpmyadmin so I assume that the 0.00003 sec is caused by the limit that phpmyadmin did to display in the table. That is why is fast, but it's very slow the other query to displya 25 rows. I updated my answer with your commands

Answer (score 1):

Given that you expect the `customers` table to be fairly large while the `offices` table to be fairly small, I can suggest indexing the former table for your join query:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON customers (id_office, firstname);  -- also includes id
```

This index covers the join condition in your query, and it also includes `firstname` to cover the select clause.  Note that InnoDB will automatically tag on the `id` primary key column to this index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I tried that and now the query run in  0.9239 seconds. It is the best we can ? And also e.g I'm in a datatable then I can sort on multiple columns so I have to add the other columns in the index ? `CREATE INDEX idx ON customers (id_office, firstname, lastname, email etc...);`

Comment: This is the best I can think of right now.  For other queries, you might need a different index.

Comment: You mean multiple index like that ? `CREATE INDEX idx ON customers (id_office, lastname);` `CREATE INDEX idx ON customers (id_office, email);`. And If I up the CPU number it will be better ?

Comment: @John - CPUs have not improved significantly in 20 years.  Don't bother.

Answer (score 0):

Are those real queries?  Or just fabricated to point out a flaw in the optimizer.  (PS, this might be a good example to file as a bug report -- bugs.mysql.com )

The only thing that `office` is doing is "and this guy has an office".  That can be achieved this way (perhaps much faster):

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstname
    FROM customers c
    WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM offices o
                    WHERE c.id_office = o.id )
    ORDER BY c.firstname
    LIMIT 25;
```

What seems to be happening with your version...  The Optimizer realizes that there is only one row in Office, so it decides to get that out of the way *first*.  But then it fails to see other things like the `ORDER BY...LIMIT`.

`0.00003 seconds` smells fishy, as if the Query cache was involved.  When timing `SELECTs`, do `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`

Comment: 0.0003 sorry. They are real yes. I do these queries to display customers with the associated office in datatable I can sort and search by columns. I tried you query but it is not faster :(. When I do my query or your query the CPU usage increase to 80 / 100% maybe should I go on no sql DB ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the single-row-table optimization is overriding any clues that `LIMIT` might give.  See if this kludge helps:

- Add a bogus row to `office`.

And add this 2-column "composite" index:  `(firstname, id_office)`

I'm hoping those will trick it into doing the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` before worrying about the size of `office`.

Comment: I already had this composite index. I added a new row to office but no changes :(

Comment: Oh well.  Thanks for testing.